# How can wrap input value text

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I have this piece of code but I am unable to wrap word.

```
<div class="added-link">
    <input type="submit" style="color: #000000;" class="addedlink"  id="abc" value="User Survey Confidentiality Statement" name="linbutton">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign some fixed `width` to your `<input type="submit" />` and use `white-space: normal;` **OR** you can just use a new line *(cheap way)* in your source HTML

```
value="User Survey
 Confidentiality Statement"
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jW7C3/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/jW7C3/1/)

```
<input type="submit" class="addedlink" value="User Survey Confidentiality Statement" name="linbutton">

.addedlink {
   color: #000000; 
   white-space: normal; 
   width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: The speed on this answer was stupidly fast. +1 (also its correct)